# SQL returning more rows after joining

Tags: sql, sql-server, oracle, join, oracle11g

I am trying to join 2 tables with following data. When I join using below query, it gets me multiple duplicate rows. I have used distinct.

Apologies in advance for incorrect or insufficient description post. Please bear with me as this is my first time posting a question on this forum.

I am using below query.

```
select a.timestamp_for_start_message, b.timestamp_for_start_message 
from start_message a, success_message b where a.id1 = b.id1 and a.jobid = b.jobid;
```

Start Message Table

```
ID1     Timestamp_start_msg_recieved    date        jobid      message
1234    5/14/2014 10:02:29              5/14/2014   abc        start
1234    5/14/2014 10:02:29              5/14/2014   abc        start
1234    5/14/2014 10:02:29              5/14/2014   abc        start
1234    5/14/2014 10:02:29              5/14/2014   abc        start
1234    5/14/2014 10:09:06              5/14/2014   abc        start
1234    5/14/2014 10:09:06              5/14/2014   abc        start
1234    5/14/2014 10:09:06              5/14/2014   abc        start
1234    5/14/2014 10:09:06              5/14/2014   abc        start
1234    5/14/2014 11:45:11              5/14/2014   abc        start
1234    5/14/2014 11:45:11              5/14/2014   abc        start
1234    5/14/2014 11:45:11              5/14/2014   abc        start
1234    5/14/2014 11:45:11              5/14/2014   abc        start
1234    5/14/2014 19:02:52              5/14/2014   abc        start
5678    5/14/2014 22:02:52              5/14/2014   pqr        start
5678    5/14/2014 23:10:40              5/14/2014   pqr        start
```

Success Message Table

```
ID1     Timestamp_success_msg_recieved  date        jobid  message
1234    5/14/2014 10:02:31              5/14/2014   abc    successful
1234    5/14/2014 10:02:31              5/14/2014   abc    successful
1234    5/14/2014 10:02:31              5/14/2014   abc    successful
1234    5/14/2014 10:02:31              5/14/2014   abc    successful
1234    5/14/2014 10:09:10              5/14/2014   abc    successful
1234    5/14/2014 10:09:10              5/14/2014   abc    successful
1234    5/14/2014 10:09:10              5/14/2014   abc    successful
1234    5/14/2014 10:09:10              5/14/2014   abc    successful
1234    5/14/2014 16:48:22              5/14/2014   abc    successful
1234    5/14/2014 19:03:00              5/14/2014   abc    successful
5678    5/14/2014 22:03:00              5/14/2014   pqr    successful
```

I am trying to get closest match between timestamps of these two tables.
Below is one other way of looking at data.
Conditions to be met: one start message can have multiple success message with same or different time stamps for same id and jobid. I need to pick max of start message to min of success message to make it a match.

```
id      Time_stamp_message_recieved  message      jobid
1234    5/14/2014 10:02:29           started      abc
1234    5/14/2014 10:02:29           started      abc
1234    5/14/2014 10:02:29           started      abc
1234    5/14/2014 10:02:29           started      abc
1234    5/14/2014 10:02:31           successful   abc
1234    5/14/2014 10:02:31           successful   abc
1234    5/14/2014 10:02:31           successful   abc
1234    5/14/2014 10:02:31           successful   abc
1234    5/14/2014 10:09:06           started      abc
1234    5/14/2014 10:09:06           started      abc
1234    5/14/2014 10:09:06           started      abc
1234    5/14/2014 10:09:06           started      abc
1234    5/14/2014 10:09:10           successful   abc
1234    5/14/2014 10:09:10           successful   abc
1234    5/14/2014 10:09:10           successful   abc
1234    5/14/2014 10:09:10           successful   abc
1234    5/14/2014 11:45:11           started      abc
1234    5/14/2014 11:45:11           started      abc
1234    5/14/2014 11:45:11           started      abc
1234    5/14/2014 11:45:11           started      abc
1234    5/14/2014 16:48:22           successful   abc
1234    5/14/2014 19:02:52           started      abc
1234    5/14/2014 19:03:00           successful   abc
```

PS: I am sorting based on ID and JOBID and TIMESTAMP in both tables and then joining based on ID and JOBID.

#### Expected Result

```
ID1  IMESTAMP_for_start_message TIMESTAMP_for_start_message  Date       Jobid    start_message
1234 5/14/2014 10:02:29         5/14/2014 10:02:31           5/14/2014  abc
1234 5/14/2014 10:09:06         5/14/2014 10:09:10           5/14/2014  abc
1234 5/14/2014 11:45:11         5/14/2014 16:48:22           5/14/2014  abc
1234 5/14/2014 19:02:52         5/14/2014 19:03:00           5/14/2014  abc
5678 5/14/2014 22:02:52         5/14/2014 22:03:00           5/14/2014  pqr
5678 5/14/2014 23:10:40         null                         5/14/2014  pqr
```

**********************Edited Question Below*****************************

Lets say I have below mentioned data in that case I am looking to get max of Start message and corresponding min or success message.

Start Message Table

```
ID1     Timestamp_start_msg_recieved    date        jobid      message
1234    5/14/2014 10:02:29              5/14/2014   abc        start
1234    5/14/2014 10:02:31              5/14/2014   abc        start
1234    5/14/2014 10:02:45              5/14/2014   abc        start
1234    5/14/2014 10:02:50              5/14/2014   abc        start
1234    5/14/2014 10:09:04              5/14/2014   abc        start
1234    5/14/2014 10:09:06              5/14/2014   abc        start
1234    5/14/2014 10:09:16              5/14/2014   abc        start
1234    5/14/2014 10:09:26              5/14/2014   abc        start
1234    5/14/2014 11:45:11              5/14/2014   abc        start
1234    5/14/2014 16:48:20              5/14/2014   abc        start
1234    5/14/2014 19:02:52              5/14/2014   abc        start
5678    5/14/2014 22:02:52              5/14/2014   pqr        start
5678    5/14/2014 23:10:40              5/14/2014   pqr        start
```

Success Message Table

```
ID1     Timestamp_success_msg_recieved  date        jobid  message
1234    5/14/2014 10:02:52              5/14/2014   abc    successful
1234    5/14/2014 10:09:32              5/14/2014   abc    successful
1234    5/14/2014 11:45:15              5/14/2014   abc    successful
1234    5/14/2014 11:45:18              5/14/2014   abc    successful
1234    5/14/2014 11:45:19              5/14/2014   abc    successful
1234    5/14/2014 11:45:25              5/14/2014   abc    successful
1234    5/14/2014 16:48:22              5/14/2014   abc    successful
1234    5/14/2014 19:03:00              5/14/2014   abc    successful
5678    5/14/2014 22:03:00              5/14/2014   pqr    successful
```

#### Expected Result

```
ID1  IMESTAMP_for_start_message TIMESTAMP_for_start_message  Date       Jobid    msg  msg
1234 5/14/2014 10:02:50         5/14/2014 10:02:52           5/14/2014  abc start success
1234 5/14/2014 10:09:26         5/14/2014 10:09:32           5/14/2014  abc start success
1234 5/14/2014 11:45:11         5/14/2014 11:45:25           5/14/2014  abc start success
1234 5/14/2014 16:48:20         5/14/2014 16:48:22           5/14/2014  abc start success
1234 5/14/2014 19:02:52         5/14/2014 19:03:00           5/14/2014  abc start success
5678 5/14/2014 22:02:52         5/14/2014 22:03:00           5/14/2014  pqr start success
5678 5/14/2014 23:10:40         null                         5/14/2014  pqr start success
```

I am looking for Max of start message to pair up with min of success message.

I am trying to get closest match between timestamps of these two tables.
Below is one other way of looking at data.
Conditions to be met: one start message can have multiple success message with same or different time stamps for same id and jobid. I need to pick max of start message to min of success message to make it a match.

```
id      Time_stamp_message_recieved  message      jobid
1234    5/14/2014 10:02:29           started      abc
1234    5/14/2014 10:02:29           started      abc
1234    5/14/2014 10:02:29           started      abc
1234    5/14/2014 10:02:29           started      abc
1234    5/14/2014 10:02:31           successful   abc
1234    5/14/2014 10:02:31           successful   abc
1234    5/14/2014 10:02:31           successful   abc
1234    5/14/2014 10:02:31           successful   abc
1234    5/14/2014 10:09:06           started      abc
1234    5/14/2014 10:09:06           started      abc
1234    5/14/2014 10:09:06           started      abc
1234    5/14/2014 10:09:06           started      abc
1234    5/14/2014 10:09:10           successful   abc
1234    5/14/2014 10:09:10           successful   abc
1234    5/14/2014 10:09:10           successful   abc
1234    5/14/2014 10:09:10           successful   abc
1234    5/14/2014 11:45:11           started      abc
1234    5/14/2014 11:45:11           started      abc
1234    5/14/2014 11:45:11           started      abc
1234    5/14/2014 11:45:11           started      abc
1234    5/14/2014 16:48:22           successful   abc
1234    5/14/2014 19:02:52           started      abc
1234    5/14/2014 19:03:00           successful   abc
```

Comment: What are your expected results?  If you're joining on the id and job, you're producing a `cartesian product` between all those date fields.  Normally you'd have a unique row identifier to join on.

Comment: I am expecting to get a close match based on timestamps of two tables.


I am joining on id and jobid which needs to be same in order to be able to get close enough match based on timestamps of both tables

Comment: i can see all your sample data is having ID1 1234 and jobid abc, how do you identify which line tie with which line ?

Comment: Um, what are your expected results -- edit your question...

Comment: @ah_hau I am sorting it based on id, jobid and Time stamps in this orde of both the tables and then joining, hoping it would match to the closest possible timestamp.

Comment: hoping it won't work, you need do it in sql, perhaps you need to join the timestamp column?

Comment: also, show your expected result like what sgeddes suggested in your question, what end result you want it to look like, show us the table, the expected data

Comment: @ah_hau:  based on study of data, sorting is helping get two closest timestamps together. Problem arises when the number of records in table1 is less than that of table2.

In such a case it multiplies records for table1 to match the record number for table2

Comment: @DataAnalyst -- without knowing your actual expected results, I don't think anyone can help you.  Hoping it to match on the closest -- what are those results with your sample data?  Are you just wanting to add `TIMESTAMP_for_success_message` to your `join`?  Maybe with an `outer join`?

Comment: I have updated the question with the expected results. I will edit and update more of the data set in a bit. I am working on getting thee sample data ready to be able to understand the nature of data better

Comment: You don't really want the same column twice in your result, do you? (Similarly "TIMESTAMP_for_success_message" in "Start Message Table" and "TIMESTAMP_for_start_message" in "Success Message Table" seem to be mixed up.)

Comment: Once sorted, the data sets appear to be identical. If so - and representative for the actual data: Why are you storing it twice, and what is the objective of the query, you seem to be looking for? Otherwise: [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/89ee4/4/2) relates to the sorting, you are suggesting to come before the join.

Comment: @Abecee: you are right. I do not need the same column or row for that matter twice in the expected result. I have modified the sample input and output data to incorporate all conditions of mismatch in timestamps.

Comment: 5678 5/14/2014 23:10:40 null 5/14/2014 pqr, so for this example, no record in success_message that is having timestamp > that? how you come out with 5/14/2014 then? also do you need to cater next day condition? Example 5/14/2014 23:59:00 vs 5/15/2014 00:01:00, are they consider paired?

Comment: On top of @ah_hau's most recent question: In your current sample data, you have four sets each with "Timestamp_start_msg_recieved" "5/14/2014 10:02:29" and "5/14/2014 10:09:06" / "Timestamp_success_msg_recieved" "5/14/2014 10:02:31" and "5/14/2014 10:09:10" - but just a single match of each of these in the expected result? And -anything else being equal- if instead of the current Timestamp_success_msg_recieved "5678 5/14/2014 22:03:00 5/14/2014 pqr" it were "5678 5/14/2014 23:13:00 5/14/2014 pqr" - would this have to be matched to the very last or the last but one "Timestamp_start" record?

Comment: Furthermore: The "date" columns seem to replicate the "Timestamp_start_msg_recieved"/"Timestamp_success_msg_recieved" day portion. If so, does it really make sense to repeat it? Which data type are you using to store the "date"?

Comment: @ah_hau: for "5678 5/14/2014 23:10:40 null 5/14/2014 pqr" there is no matching record in success message that is having timestamp greater than the start message. 

Yes, I need to consider next day condition as they are consdiered a pair too

Comment: @Abecee: date column can be removed. It is a substr of start message. Each of these timestamps are for a particular id. and we expect to see a success message after a start message is seen.

There could be multiple success messages for a start message and vice versa, in that case I need to take Max of start and Min of success message.

Comment: Thanks for the update. Don't really understand, how the "Max of start and Min of success message" is supposed to work in "There could be multiple success messages for a start message and vice versa, in that case I need to take Max of start and Min of success message.". Could you run updated [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/a5e2c1/10/0) against your actual data, and update your sample data to clarify?

Comment: @Abecee: the query looks to meet all of those conditions on sample data. I am trying that on actual data and will post updated sample data set shortly.

I really appreciate your guidance here.

Comment: Are there any more updates coming up?

Comment: @Abecee: I have been away for a while. Since the data that I am running this query on, is pretty huge, it is been taking too long to return results. Is there a way that I could optimize this query. I checked the output on the sample data and it works fine.

Comment: @Abecee: 1. No I do not have indices on the columns. (ii) Yes, that is case with real data too. (iii). Occasional (iv) Most of the times I need full result set. Currently I am running this query for only a month and it is already taken more than 1.5 hours. Could you please help me in optimizing this query to be able to get faster results??? –

Comment: I need this out tomorrow. Any help is appreciated. Please guide fellow scholars on this issue.

Comment: I am looking to improve the self join by adding indices to the same. could you please guide me how to do that? Current query is taking a lot of time

Answer (score 0):

Your query is:

```
select a.timestamp_for_start_message, b.timestamp_for_start_message
from start_message a join
     success_message b
where a.id1 = b.id1 and a.jobid = b.jobid;
```

Of course this produces duplicates.  Every row in your sample data has the same value for `id` and `jobid`.

It would appear that the time stamp is also a join key.  You seem to be looking for equality, so you can do:

```
select a.timestamp_for_start_message, b.timestamp_for_start_message
from start_message a join
     success_message b
where a.id1 = b.id1 and a.jobid = b.jobid and
      a.TIMESTAMP_for_start_message = b.TIMESTAMP_for_success_message
```

Comment: 1 more condition is he want to find the nearest timestamp if matching record not found

Comment: @ah_hau . . . In the sample output, all the time values are the same.

Comment: @ah_hau: I have updated sample input and output expected with more combinations.

Looks like in my previous version of sample data I had not incorporated different possibilities and hence GordonLinoff assumption about timestamps been same.

Please any guidance is valuable to me.

Appreciate all your help!

Comment: @GordonLinoff: with previous sample data, where the timestamps looked same it was correct to join them in order to remove duplicate values.

I have updated the sample data to have different combinations as expected in real data set.

Answer (score 0):

With the most current sample data, this does apparently still serve the purpose:

```sql
SELECT
  DISTINCT
  StMT.id1
  , TIMESTAMP_for_start_message
  , (SELECT MIN(TIMESTAMP_for_success_message)
     FROM SuccessMessageTable
     WHERE
       (id1 = StMT.id1)
       AND (someDate = StMT.someDate)
       AND (jobID = StMT.jobID)
       AND (TIMESTAMP_for_success_message >= StMT.TIMESTAMP_for_start_message)) TIMESTAMP_for_success_message
  , StMT.someDate
  , StMT.jobID
  , NULL start_message
FROM StartMessageTable StMT
ORDER BY id1, jobID, TIMESTAMP_for_start_message;
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/dc727a/1/0)

Comment: Thanks for the feedback regarding the sample data. As for the query not to return on the real data: (i) Do you have indices on the columns in the query? Which ones? (ii) The sample data has apparently identical rows. Is that the case for the real data as well? Any chance for some pre-processing to reduce the amount of data to be handled? (iii) What kind is your overall use case: (a) One time only? (b) Occassional - but not (c) ad hoc? (iv) Do you always need the full (result) set - or just a slice?

Comment: 1. No I do not have indices on the columns. (ii) Yes, that is case with real data too. (iii). Occasional (iv) Most of the times I need full result set. Currently I am running this query for only a month and it is already taken more than 1.5 hours. Could you please help me in optimizing this query to be able to get faster results???

Comment: I'd probably start with a single index on all three/four of id1, jobID, TIMESTAMP_for_start_message (and someDate). Index order of the columns must be the same for both tables. Pre-processing (into temporary tables) would be another option - and/or use of materialized views. Why do you have these repeat rows? If they are really identical (over all columns) - any chance to get rid of them? Or is there any business value in their being duplicate? (In case, you need the count, you could have table, which does point to a single copy of each set - with the additional copies actually being deleted.)

Comment: How much progress did you make?

Comment: I used temporary table method with below query. But looks like it gives me only the min of success message. Here is my query


WITH DATA AS(
SELECT MIN(SMT.timestamp_for_success_message)timestamp_for_success_message
     FROM success_table1 SMT, start_table2 b
     WHERE
       (SMT.id1 = b.id1)
       AND (SMT.jobid = b.jobid)
       AND (SMT.date >= b.date)
)
SELECT a.timestamp_for_success_message, b.id1, b.jobid, b.somedate, b.column8 FROM data a, start_table2 b;

Comment: I am looking to get min of success message and max of start message for a given id and jobid. The above query is not serving the purpose.

Comment: (i) Did you give the indices a try? (ii) How did you create and fill the temporary table? (iii) Did you eliminate the duplicate data? (iv) How did you end up with that query?

Comment: No, I have not tried adding indices, as I am not quite sure how to go about it. I am using WITH clause to create temporary table which pulls out MIN of success message timestamp and then use that column to pair up with other columns like id and jobid and start message timestamp. The reason I ended up with this query is that the self join where in I am selecting min is scanning whole table all over again and reducing efficiency since I am dealing with huge amount of data here.

Comment: The query, I supplied earlier, did -if I got you correctly- return the correct result. [Creating indices](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/statements_5011.htm#SQLRF01209) is pretty straightforward. The best candidates (based on information supplied) have been provided earlier. BTW: With all the duplicate data, joins (no matter, whether established using `JOIN`or `WHERE`) are likely to create (at least temporarily) larger (intermediate) data sets. When I spoke of temporary tables, I didn't think of `WITH` but of actual `CREATE` - to really cut down the amount of data.

Comment: yes, it did help and I could get min of success message timestamp. What I did not include in the earlier sample dataset was condition where I have multiple starts with single success and vice versa. Also the query almost got stuck up with scanning two tables having million records and hence the temp table query research.

Comment: Sorry - I'm pretty much lost: By now, you opened three requests on this topic - and the requirements keep changing. Indices are apparently still not in place. Somewhere you mention pulling the data from four different tables. Missing just one join condition could be the reason for the query not to return on the actual data. (i) When you say MAX(start) and MIN(success) - is this always within some specific minute or could the start minute be different from the success minute?

Comment: (ii) If you still have the mentioned duplicates in the actual data: Why can't you just delete them? What are they adding to the picture - except for requiring processing time, and making the alignment harder? (iii) In the sample data, you have more than one row for, e.g., the combination of ID1 "1234" and jobID "abc". This seems to contradict a comment of yours.

Comment: (iv) Did you try to run the query on just a week's/day's/hour's worth of data - to get an idea, where about the trouble starts? (v) Do you have full power over the database? Could you create materialized views? -- If you still need assistance: Getting your requirements straight, and creating indices on the columns involved in the joins would help tremendously.

Comment: (i)there is no restriction on minutes. It could have occurred at any time. The seconds column in the other post shows that I have 2 separate columns(start_timestamp,start_secs) for a start message and similar for success message. (ii)there are other columns in the data set which makes it the unique if included int he table.Since I have not shown those columns here it looks like duplicates.(iii)I have multiple entries of id1 and jobid combination having different start/success timestamps.(iv)I ran the query on sample data and it worked fine giving results in secs.

Comment: (v) No I am not able to create views.